# is there any free java(grails)(tomcat) hosting server?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I want to host my grails application in net for testing ...
is there any free server sites?

supports grails,mysql

Comment: Sorry, questions about free hosting services are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: sorry to hear that

Answer (score 0):

You could give the new cloud platform [CloudFoundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/) a shot. It uses Tomcat under the covers. You have to sign up for an account first. It might take a couple of days until you get your account approved.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon EC2 free tier that Bozho mentioned is available for use with Elastic Beanstalk - http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/#pricing . It supports Tomcat:

> The first release of Elastic Beanstalk
>   is built for Java developers using the
>   familiar Apache Tomcat software stack
>   which ensures easy portability for
>   your application.